# How to programmatically get the list of symbols restricted in variable names

Tags: c#

Just curios is there any way to get the list of symbols that are illegal for naming variables in C# e.g. brackets of all kinds, commas etc in code? Something like `SomeClass.GetIllegalVariableSymbols()`

Comment: You might be able to find something in the [Roslyn Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) preview (an API for the C# compiler). [`CandidateSymbols`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx#Toc306015694) looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; there are *a lot*, for one, when you consider Unicode, and there are also other rules (e.g. an identifier can contain a number but not begin with one, keywords can’t be used as identifiers unless prefixed by an `@`, etc.).

You’ll need to build your own appropriate for the situation. (What is that, out of curiosity?)

Comment: Well, this idea came to my mind when I was inspecting SharedSizeGroup property of ColumnDefinition. As it is described in MSDN it can't hold anything besides letters, digits and underscores

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Just use Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() method.
[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know a same rule applies to both

Comment: The following reserved characters:

< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)

In the variable name you can not also use dots and commas. [Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: And what about the space character?